# Read csv file from media folder

Tags: python, django, hosting, media, namecheap

I uploaded my app to hosting

I want read the csv file from media folder

but display error FileNotFoundError

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ed/public_html/myproject/project\media\A.csv'

App before upload was working

> setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

if DEBUG:

    STATICFILES_DIRS = ['/home/ed/public_html/myproject/project/static']

else:

   STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ed/public_html/myproject/project/static'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/ed/public_html/myproject/project/media'
```

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

> view.py

```
 def test(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        print(uploaded_file)
        if uploaded_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
            #save file in media folder
            savefile = FileSystemStorage()
            name = savefile.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file) #name of the file
            #know where to save file
            d = os.getcwd() #current directory of the project
            file_directory = d + '\media\\' + name
            readfile(file_directory)
            return redirect(results)
       else:
             messages.warning(request, 'File was not uploaded. Please use csv file!')

    return render(request, 'test.html', {})
```

Looking forward to hearing from you

Answer (score 0):

your static and media root is incorrect. It is not a way to do like this.

do this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_URL='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

Comment: I did that but the page don't working gives me the error Internal Server Error 500

Comment: you are getting this error because in settings file there is DEBUG False, In your settings file, add DEBUG=True. Then it will solve the error

Comment: DEBUG=True In settings file. the app working before uploaded to hosting, but after display the error

Comment: then make it false if it is hosted

Comment: I did that but the page don't working gives me the error Internal Server Error 500

Comment: please provide that error here only

Comment: Are the (static\media) settings in the local different from hosting

Comment: static and media files are different